# Javascript in localStorage

Tags: javascript, browser

I randomly found out that in my localStorage is saved a string which is a minified javascript library. Here is it how it starts:

```
Riot.DDragon.fn={};
Riot.DDragon.dataTypes="item,champion,mastery,rune,summoner,language".split(",");
(function(){
  function k(a,d){
    switch(d){
      default:
      case "normal":
        return a;
      case "small":
        return parseInt(0.75*a);
      case "tiny":
        return parseInt(0.5*a)
    }
  }
}
```

and it continues as it is too much to paste here. It was all on one line saved as a string but I made it readable a little. My question is why would you save javascript in the localStorage?

Comment: Can you clarify on the actual question?

Comment: Quick google search leads to https://developer.riotgames.com/ (ask there). It appears to have something to do with the game League of Legends. As for why one would store JS code in local storage; I can think of several reasons but not a single good one.

Comment: Take a look at this post for some details about reasons for choosing to place javascript in localstorge: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/105524/is-it-realistic-to-make-use-of-html5-local-storage-to-store-css-and-javascript